# Почему не срабатывает событие onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется такой компонент (все лишнее из него убрал)

В WorkItem элементах прописывается `onClick={() => {alert(1)}}`, но по какой-то причине событие не срабатывает, из-за чего это может быть?

P.S. Проверил чтобы поверх элемента не было других элементов, т.е. клику по элементу ничего не мешает.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

import WorkItem from '../WorkItem';

class PortfolioSectionPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        

    }
    
    render() {


        //Расположение кругов
        let workItems;

        if(this.state.showWorks) {
            let {works} = this.state;

            const angleRad = 360 / works.length * 0.017; //Частота кругов в радианах
            const bg = document.getElementById('portfolio-panel-disk');
            let radius;
            if(bg) {
                radius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(bg).width) / 2;
            }

            workItems = works.map((currentValue, index) => {
                return <WorkItem
                        onClick={() => {alert(1)}} 
                        type={currentValue.type} 
                        link={currentValue.link} 
                        key={index + 50} 
                        leftOffset={radius - radius * Math.cos(angleRad * index)}
                        topOffset={radius - radius * Math.sin(angleRad * index)}
                        angle={-this.state.wheelAngleinDeg}  />
            })
        } else {
            workItems = null;
        }

        let diskStyle = {
            transform: `translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(${this.state.wheelAngleinDeg}deg)`,
        };

                                    
         

        return(

            <div className='portfolio-panel' id='porfolioPanel' ref={this.props.link}>
                <div className='portfolio-panel-background' 
                     ref={this.props.linkCircle} 
                     onTransitionEnd={(e) => {this.showWorks(e)}}
                 >
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup onTransitionEnd={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}
                        transitionName='portfolio-panel__information'
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                            {middleElementCircle}
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    <div style={diskStyle} className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup onTransitionEnd={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}
                        transitionName='work-item'
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                            {workItems}
                        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    

export default PortfolioSectionPanel;
```

Comment: Потому что вы вставляете `WorkItem`. Повесьте `onclick` непосредственно в нём. Так получается вы передаётся функцию через `props`

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, как это сделать? У меня 5 элементов workItem, и у каждого должен быть свой onClick с функцией в которую будет передаваться определенный аргумент, для каждого элемента этот аргумент свой

Comment: Значит на каждый `workItem` вешаете `onClick` внутри него. Опр. аргумент передаёте через пропсы и передаётся его в `onClick` -- `onClick={() => alert(props.something)`.

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, не могу понять куда это прописывать вообще :)

Как понять внутри его? Можете дать пример?)

Comment: Вы импортируете `workItem`. Перейди в этот компонент. И на самом верхнем  элемент(div, section, не знаю, что там у вас) повесьте её

Answer (score 1):

onClick нельзя повесить на сам компонет т.к. компонет это абстракия в DOM его нет.
Поэтому сделайте так - в НОС компоненте обявляете функцию с исполняемым кодом, передаёте эту функцию в простой компонет и уже в нём на нужном элементе вызываете onClick с этой функцией.

Код писал на коленке, но должно всё работать ...

```
import React, { Component  } from 'react';

export default class PortfolioSectionPanel extends Component {
    hendelClick = () => {
        alert(1)
    }
    render() {
        // ....
        workItems = works.map((v, i) => {
            return <WorkItem
                    hendelClick={this.hendelClick}
                    // ...
                    />
        })
        // ....
        return (
            <>
                {/*Ваш код*/}
            </>
        )
    }
}

const WorkItem = ({
    hendelClick
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={hendelClick}></div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default WorkItem
```